# Form Input Field not in line for Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I have 4 form fields in the form and two fields in each row. The title of one field is very long so the form field is shifted down while the other form field title is small so there is a mis-alignment in the form. Ex:

```
Very long Field name                      Small field name
that is wrapped in three                  __________________
lines
______________________   

Field 3                                   Field 4
______________________                    ___________________
```

The very long field name and small field name input should be in the same line like:

```
Very long Field name                      Small field name
that is wrapped in three                  
lines
______________________                   ___________________
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>form field name</label>
<input type="text">
</div>
```

In CSS I tried:

```
.form-group{
flex:60%;
```

Comment: so there are different ways to achieve but the solution you are looking is not a permanent solution. Because when screen size will change may be that will wrapped in 4 lines so you can not think of a possible padding. Have you tried using word wrap and a tool tip ? Are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4. Can you please explain what would be the best permanent solution? Thank you

Comment: you can create a wrapper class and allow count, which can be wrapped up in a line and give your label a min-height. After that you can use tool tip to tell user what is the full name. In this case your space will never be broken even if the full label is way big than you imagination. And your tool tip will explain the full name to user. I can give you a solution if this suits your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `min-height` to label with CSS equal with the height of the biggest label. See example below:

```html
<div style="width: 150px;display: inline-block;">
    <label style="min-height: 50px; display: block;">form field name</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div style="width: 150px; display: inline-block;">
    <label for="">
        Very long Field name that is wrapped in three lines
        <input type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Providing an example can go a long way to improve your answer.

Comment: i updated my answer providing an example with your code,
i hope you will find it helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular flex layout to handle this. This would dynamically change the height based on length of the text

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
    <label>Very long Field name that is wrapped in three lines</label>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
    <label>Small field name</label>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```